# Search stopped by input onBlur

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I designed this simple search that shows up with an animation once you click search. My problem is that I want to reuse the Search button to allow users to click it again to actually search once they've typed something.

Clicking the button again fires onBlur which loses focus and my input goes away and then triggers the Search again. What can I do to make it actually perform the search rather than trigger onBlur...

Desired effect: Click Search, input shows up, click outside of input, input goes away because of onBlur, click search again, type something, clicking search doesn't trigger onBlur but actually perform a search e.g by calling a different function.

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Nav = () => {
  const [isSearchOn, setIsSearchOn] = useState(false);
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");
  let searchInput;

  const onSearchBlur = () => {
    setIsSearchOn(false);
    setSearchValue("");
    console.log("onBlur ", searchValue);
  };

  const onSearchChange = event => {
    setSearchValue(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSearchClick = () => {
    if (!isSearchOn) {
      setIsSearchOn(true);
      searchInput.focus();
    }

    console.log("searchClick = ", isSearchOn);
  };

  const handleSearch = () => {
    console.log("Perform the search");
  };

  return (
    <nav>
      <input
        value={searchValue}
        id="search"
        placeholder="Search..."
        className={isSearchOn ? "search-on" : ""}
        ref={input => {
          searchInput = input;
        }}
        onChange={onSearchChange}
        onBlur={onSearchBlur}
      />
          
      <button onClick={handleSearchClick}>
        Search
      </button>
    </nav>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Nav />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #444;
}

input {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.2s;
}

input:focus {
  transform: translateX(0);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`e.preventDefault` is your possible solution. I modified your search handler like below. You essentially want to prevent event from bubbling up. here's the working version which you can play with: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xis1gp

```
const { useState } = React;

export const Nav = () => {
  const [isSearchOn, setIsSearchOn] = useState(false);
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");
  let searchInput;

  const onSearchBlur = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsSearchOn(false);
    setSearchValue("");
    console.log("onBlur ", searchValue);
  };

  const onSearchChange = event => {
    setSearchValue(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSearchClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!isSearchOn) {
      setIsSearchOn(true);
      searchInput.focus();
    }

    console.log("searchClick = ", isSearchOn);
  };

  const handleSearch = () => {
    console.log("Perform the search");
  };

  return (
    <nav>
      <input
        value={searchValue}
        id="search"
        placeholder="Search..."
        className={isSearchOn ? "search-on" : ""}
        ref={input => {
          searchInput = input;
        }}
        onChange={onSearchChange}
        onBlur={onSearchBlur}
      />

      <button onClick={handleSearchClick}>
        Search
      </button>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make any difference.

Comment: ok Edited and this seems like working however not an ideal implementation it seems as it goes back to input as focus clearing value of the user entry. Anyway that's usecase concern so no comment on that

Comment: It still does the same thing preventDefault() doesn't seem to be making a difference. Just tried it with and without. Clicking search the second time is still going to trigger onBlur and eventDefault isn't stopping that. This means the search input goes away and comes back.